# Get subscribers name from youtube

Tags: php, youtube

I've searched high and low (for about half an hour :)) but can't seem to find a way to get a list of subscriber names from a channel.

In my case i want to use it in a livesteam on youtube. My recording software let's me load a webpage that i use to show some informtion (like the amount of subscribers).

However, with some refreshing on the code to see if a new subscribers has come i would like to show it's name on the livesteam.

Therefor i need some 'request' to show me the latest subscriber on my channel from youtube.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parameter **myRecentSubscribers**

> **boolean**
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly authorized request. Set
> this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the subscribers
> of the authenticated user in reverse chronological order (newest
> first).
>
> Note that this parameter only supports retrieval of the most recent
> 1000 subscribers to the authenticated user's channel. To retrieve a
> complete list of subscribers, use the mySubscribers parameter. That
> parameter, which does not return subscribers in a particular order,
> does not limit the number of subscribers that can be retrieved.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

> This example retrieves a list of channels that the specified channel subscribes to. In this example, the API response lists channels to which the GoogleDevelopers channel subscribes.

```
// Sample php code for subscriptions.list

function subscriptionsListByChannelId($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->subscriptions->listSubscriptions(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

subscriptionsListByChannelId($service,
    'snippet,contentDetails', 
    array('channelId' => 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw'));
```

Comment: To bad, the 'subscribtions' gives a readout of subscribed channels by the channel owner. In no way above code list any subscribers (the users subscribing to the given channel).

Comment: It can give a readout of subscribed channels, what's returned depends on the parameters you call with. I've edited my post to make it more clear how to do exactly what you're asking for. Look at the parameters in the documentation that return subscribers, there's more than one.